# Multiplication between elements in $S_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have trouble understanding how to multiply elements in $S_3$ with elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. I believe I am supposed to use that if $\circ$ is the operation on $G$ and $\bullet$ is the operation on $H$, then $(g,h)*(g',h') = (g\circ g', h \bullet h')$.

So the group operation for $S_3$ is composition. The group operation for $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is multiplication modulo $2$. If $g$ is the function that takes $123$ to $213$ and $h$ is the function that takes $123$ to $321$, and lets say $g' = 0$ and $h' = 1$, then we'd have $(g,h)*(0,1) = (g \circ 0, h \bullet 1), $ but that doesn't really seem to make sense, at least not in a way that I understand.

Can I perhaps choose some other group operation for $\mathbb{Z}_2$? Any suggestions?

Context: I am trying to understand why/how $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is a non-abelian group of order $12$, and particularly what the elements in this group look like.

Comment: $(0,1)$ is not a valid pair in $S_3\times \Bbb Z/2$, or what should $0\in S_3$ be? So your product $(g,h)*(0,1)$ does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is the group composition for the direct product $S_3\times \Bbb Z/2$, but you applied it in the wrong order, i.e., the pair $(0,1)$ is not in $S_3\times \Bbb Z/2$, as it should.

The group $S_3\times \Bbb Z/2$ consists of the following $12$ elements:
$$
(id,0),((123),0),((132),0),((12),0),((13),0),((23),0)), (id,1),((123),1),((132),1),((12),1),((13),1),((23),1)).
$$

This is how a direct product $G\times H$ of two groups is defined as a set. This set of ordered pairs becomes a group via the composition
$$
(g,h)\circ (g',h')=(gg',hh').
$$

Comment: What is the difference between a direct product and a product? And how does what I wrote even make sense, I mean, what IS e.g. the element $g \circ 0$?

Comment: "And how does what I wrote even make sense" - well, you should know what you meant. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Maybe should mention some more context: $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is used as an example of a non-abelian group of order 12. So I am trying to figure out why that is.

Comment: This is easy, and goes as you said. Define a composition of ordered pairs by $(g,h)\circ (c,d):=(gc,hd)$ for $(g,h),(c,d)\in S_3\times \Bbb Z/2$.Here the group product $gc$ is in $S_3$ and the other one in $\Bbb Z/2$, so this makes sense.

Comment: Now that makes sense to me. Thank you. :)